# Numerical methods to solve a positive semi-definite linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I am currently solving a problem that in the process ends up having to solve a linear system. The matrix of this system is not always positive-definite, and at most this matrix can be positive semi-definite.

In the case that the matrix is positive-definite, I use a Cholesky decomposition in the matrix to solve the system. In the other case, I'm using a [Conjugated Gradient Least Square algorithm](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/cgls/), but I don't know if it's the best way out.

Could you give me suggestions/algorithms for a linear system whose matrix is positive semi-definite?

Comment: If the matrix is positive semi-definite but not positive definite, then the matrix is not invertible. Are you sure there's even a solution in that case?

Comment: Hi @littleO. In fact, when the matrix of the linear system is not well conditioned, there is no guarantee of finding a single exact solution. In the case that the matrix is semi-defined positive, its eigenvalues are very close to zero, which tends to hinder the inversion of the matrix. So, getting an exact solution is complicated, but an approximate solution can offer a way out. I have been reading the book "Matrix Computations" by Gene Golub to help me, but I am asking here to speed up the process ;)

Comment: Is there any way to add a "regularization term" to your problem formulation to make the resulting linear system more well conditioned? One brute force approach might be to simply replace the linear system $Ax = b$ with $(A + \lambda I)x = b$, where $\lambda$ is a small positive number. Perhaps there is a more principled approach that involves adding regularization to your model, in some sense.

Comment: @littleO it's a good one, but I was trying not to use regularization, actually. A point with a Tikhonov-style regularization (ridge, just like you suggested) would be to get which value most suitable for the regularization parameter, and doing a cross-validation (or some k-folds) slows down my algorithm .-.. And another point is because my algorithm already has other parameters (which do not influence this linear system, in this case), and I was trying to avoid. I would like to know even if someone knew more iterative-algorithms to solve this type of problem beyond than regularization